# How can I put different textures/materials on different parts of the same mesh?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing, uv, blender-internal-render-engine

Title pretty much says it all. I have just started using blender 2.7, been on it for about a month, and have spent hours watching tutorials and reading and playing around with it.

I have built a model of a house, not for anything specific just wanted to do a whole model from start to finish as a learning project. I am happy with the model but I just can't get the textures to work. I am using cycles render but have also tried blender render. I textured the roof: marked seams>unwrapped>new material> nodes etc, and it looked really good, I was happy with it, so I marked seams for the door frame, unwrapped and set the texture and nodes etc but the wood texture applied itself to the roof as well as the door and made the rest of the model go a brown colour with out displaying the texture. I played around with the roof and got the right texture to display again, but it displayed on the door as well.

I really don't know what I am doing wrong, even when I follow a tutorial it doesn't work for me. I even tried a simple sword model, thinking the house might just be too much for a beginner, but the texture for the handle would assign itself to the whole model, none of my textures will stay seperate like I want them to.

This is really frustrating me as I am eager to learn and this would be an amazing skill to learn alongside my computer science degree, but it just won't work. Hopefully I am just missing something really simple and obvious, but a knowledgeable helping hand would be great.

Many thanks.

Edit: the post marked as the same as this one hasn't helped, I have worked through that thread a few times and it hasn't solved my issue. The uv maps won't hold seperate textures for me, blender applies the latest texture to every material and uv map on my project.

Comment: I have seen that post and worked through it quite a few times but it hasn't helped. I have tried using different uv maps for each part of my model but the textures I am applying are showing on every part of the model that I have worked on. I can't have a roof texture on the roof and a wood texture on the door and brick texture etc etc because every time I do the next section of my model it replaces all the previous textures I have done, eg: roof shows the door texture, then the roof and door show the brick texture etc.

Comment: Do you click *Assign* button each time you select adjacent parts of the mesh and create new material ?

Comment: I have tried clicking assign and new material, I've tried not clicking assign as well.

Comment: Every uv map I use has a different node setup, each one has its own texture node with a different image opened but whenever I do a different section of my model it over rides the textures I have already done.

Comment: Upload your file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ so we can take a look.

Comment: OK thank you, I hadn't heard of that site. Will be able to upload it sometime this evening. Thank you.

Comment: I think you may be confusing different things or using wrong terminology. Uvmaps don't use nodes, and there is no way one texture could be bleeding into a different material slot. There are *Textures, *Materials* and *UV Maps* and *Material Slots*, they are all distinct stuff.

Comment: Im pretty sure my terminology is off lol, i am still really new to blender. What I meant was i make a new unwrap for each part of the model I want to texture, I then set up my nodes in cycles render, attach a texture node, point it to the new uv unwrap for that section and add any shaders that I want on it. It works absolutely fine on the first go, but when I do the next section of my model it all seems to go ok but when I attach the texture node it overwrites the texture I did previously for a completely different part of my model.

Comment: I have uploaded my .blend file to blend-exchange:  [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2041" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2041/)

Comment: As far as I can see the question still is a duplicate. All the mesh uses one material. The reason for that is when material is created it's automatically assigned to all the faces. You should create new one, assign some faces to that and only then will you have those faces go away of the first material. To check where is material assigned click *Select* just next to *Assign*.

Comment: I have managed to do it. I think it was the way I was doing the seams which was messing it up. Thank you to everybody who took the time to answer and try and help, I really appreciate it. Thank you.